# Установить заголовок в ответе от Django

Tags: python, ajax, django

Ajax'ом обращаюсь к Django:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
$("#end-of-registration").click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        /*url: "http://localhost:8000/registration",*/
        url: "http://localhost:8000/registration",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

В вьюхе возвращаю ответ (`return HttpResponse('some text')`), но в консоли выпадает ошибка:

> ```
> Failed to load http://localhost:8000/registration: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
> ```

Нужно установить в `HttpResponse` заголовок 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *', но пока все способы оборачиваются неудачей

Comment: Здесь решение вашей проблемы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355540/access-control-allow-origin-in-django-app-when-accessed-with-phonegap

Comment: Спасибо, как оказалось, мои методы тоже были правильными, просто возвращал значение не в том блоке